# How to draw GTK stock image inside DrawingArea

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I'm writig a simple file browser in GTK#. I want to draw a stock image of a directory inside DrawingArea. I don't want to load external image. I came up to use Gdk.PixBuf but can't figure out how to load stock images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing that, but I believe [gtk_icon_theme_load_icon()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkIconTheme.html#gtk-icon-theme-load-icon) is the one that is not deprecated and is compatible with most GTK+ versions. You will need a icon GtkIconTheme as a parameter, but in most cases gtk_icon_theme_get_default() is what you want. The icon name parameter is from [Icon naming spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so rendering stock items inside DrawingArea is a bit ricky.

```
private Gdk.GC gc;
private Gdk.Pixbuf pixbuf;

public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build ();
    this.gc = new Gdk.GC((Gdk.Drawable)this.browserArea.GdkWindow);
//the method below does the trick. It is the only method I found that will return
//a valid pixbuf, so you can easily draw with the "usual" DrawPixbuf method in the 
//ExposeEvent
    this.pixbuf = RenderIcon(Gtk.Stock.Cdrom, IconSize.Dialog, "");
    this.browserArea.ExposeEvent += new ExposeEventHandler(OnExposeEvent);
}

protected void OnExposeEvent(object sender, ExposeEventArgs args){
    this.browserArea.GdkWindow.DrawPixbuf(this.gc, this.pixbuf,0,0,20,20,-1,-1,Gdk.RgbDither.None,0,0);
}
```

Comment: RenderIcon() refers to gtk_widget_render_icon() right? The function is usable of course but it's worth acknowledging that it was deprecated in GTK+ 3.0 already, and other functions in that family will be deprecated in GTK+ 3.10.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Your answer seems more up to date.